# iOS 8 Keyboard - disturbing my UI

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios8

Currently i am updating a application to iOS 8. I am facing a new problem in Keyboard.

This keyboard hiding my textfield half. What i have to change for this?.

[image]

Comment: What you always do: scrolling the screen up, so that the text field will be visible.

Comment: Take a look at my solution in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213681/ios-8-keyboard-hides-my-textview/26226732#26226732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this worked for me.

First I binded a NSLayoutConstraint that already had.

```
__weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomInputConstraint;
```

Then I subscribed to the keyboard's notification on **viewDidLoad**.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                             object:nil];
}
```

**keyboardWillShow:** method looks something like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];

    bottomInputConstraint.constant = keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height + kBottomKeyboardMargin;
}
```